# SL4A Python script can't find file

Tags: android, python, file, sl4a

So I am trying to run a simple python script using SL4A after pushing my python script and a text file (no extension) into `/sdcard/sl4a/scripts`. Unfortunately, when I use SL4A to run the script inside the terminal it exits with a traceback error stating that my file has not been found (when it tries to open it for reading). I have inspected the directory and find the file `ref` present in there. Is there something that I am missing?

EDIT: I failed to mention that I am not actually "opening" the file per se, but using linecache module to get lines. I don't think that should make a difference though.

Comment: Try placing the non-script file, in the parent directory, `/sdcard/sl4a/`. Another test you can do is to programmatically create a file within a script, and then see where that file ends up being created. You should place your file in *that* directory.

Comment: Good advice, the 'file creation' method, I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Good call, it was `/sdcard/sl4a/`